# how to change the data of line chart on datagrid itemclick in FLEX

Tags: apache-flex

I have created a line chart and another datagrid.based on dataitem clicked nthe chart should be changed.
For example
  I have datagrid for stocks with 3 stocks GOOGL,Yahoo and ADBE .On clicking upon the GOOGL the google data should be loaded in to line chart.

Please help me...!!!!

Comment: Did you mean line chart?

Answer (score 0):

There are going to be many different ways to accomplish this goal. 
The example I am giving here is based on `itemClick event on a datagrid, however you could also accomplish the same using bindings.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.charts.series.LineSeries;
        import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridItemRenderer;

        [Bindable]
        public var stocks:Array = 
            [
            {
                name: "goog", 
                values: 
                [
                { x:1, y:2 },
                    { x:2, y:8 },
                    { x:3, y:6 },
                    { x:4, y:4 }
                ]
            } ,
            {
                name: "ibm",
                values: 
                [
                { x:1, y:12 },
                    { x:2, y:4 },
                    { x:3, y:5 },
                    { x:4, y:6 }
                ]
            }
            ];


        protected function datagrid_itemClickHandler(event:ListEvent):void
        {
            var i:int;
            i = 2;
            var data:Object = (event.itemRenderer as DataGridItemRenderer).data;
            var line:LineSeries = new LineSeries();
            line.dataProvider = data.values;
            line.xField = "x";
            line.yField = "y";
            chart.series = [line];
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout />
</s:layout>
<mx:LineChart id="chart" dataProvider="{stocks}">

</mx:LineChart>
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{stocks}"
             itemClick="datagrid_itemClickHandler(event)"/>
```